# NGXS router plugin breaks routing

Tags: angular, angular-routing, ngxs

`@ngxs/storage-plugin` used with `@ngxs/router-plugin` causes routes to break.  If I remove either of them routing works fine.  With both of them, if I type a URL in the browser it always returns to the last route.  I've tried changing the order that these plugins are loaded (moving storage-plugin to last), the behavior is the same.

I have the following routes in my `app.routes.ts` module.

```
export const routes: Route[] = [
{
  path: 'login',
  children: AUTH_ROUTES
},
{
  path: 'account-verification',
  loadChildren: 'app/account-verification/account-verification.module#AccountVerificationModule'
},
{
  path: 'profile',
  loadChildren: 'app/profile/profile.module#ProfileModule'
},
{
  path: '',
  component: LayoutComponent,
  children: [
    { path: '', loadChildren: 'app/user-dashboard/user-dashboard.module#UserDashboardModule' },
    { path: 'calendar', loadChildren: 'app/calendar/calendar.module#CalendarModule' },
    // { path: 'messages', loadChildren: 'app/messaging/messaging.module#MessagingModule' },
  ],
  canActivate: [ guards.AuthGuard, guards.AccountVerificationGuard ]
}
];
```

I can navigate from `/profile/create` (a child route in ProfileModule) to `login` with no problems.

Clicking on buttons to go to a route using `[routerLink]` still works, but if I'm on `/profile/create` and I type in `/login` in the browser, I am immediately brought back to `/profile/create`.  Here are my imports in `app.module.ts`:

```
imports: [
BrowserModule,
AuthModule,
CoreModule,
HttpClientModule,
LayoutModule,
AngularFontAwesomeModule,
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { enableTracing: true }),
NgxsModule.forRoot([]),
NgxsReduxDevtoolsPluginModule.forRoot(),
NgxsStoragePluginModule.forRoot(),
NgxsRouterPluginModule.forRoot(),
ToastrModule.forRoot({
  timeOut: 10000,
  positionClass: 'toast-top-right',
  preventDuplicates: true,
}),
ToastContainerModule,
BrowserAnimationsModule,
FileUploadModule
],
```

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
  "@angular/animations": "6.0.4",
  "@angular/cdk": "6.2.1",
  "@angular/common": "6.0.4",
  "@angular/compiler": "6.0.4",
  "@angular/core": "6.0.4",
  "@angular/forms": "6.0.4",
  "@angular/http": "6.0.4",
  "@angular/material": "6.2.1",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "6.0.4",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "6.0.4",
  "@angular/router": "6.0.4",
  "@ngxs/router-plugin": "3.1.3",
  "@ngxs/storage-plugin": "3.1.3",
  "@ngxs/store": "3.1.3",
```

Comment: Are you able to create a repro using Stack Blitz?

Comment: I got an answer in the NGXS slack channel, router state should not be serialized, so I needed to specify which nodes to serialize in NgxsStoragePluginModule.forRoot({ key: ['auth'] }) so in that case I'm only serializing the auth node.  Then the router node is not serialized.

Comment: Thanks for adding what you found @RyanLangton. I did the same thing, but still get the route returning to the previous route set by this.store.dispatch(new Navigate(['/dashboard']). When I check local storage, the only key in there is the auth key with associated state values. Do you have any idea what could be happening? Is there something more that you did to get your application working correctly?

Comment: Why should router state not be serialized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What i got on NXGXS community and NGXS docs. This is bug in NGXS but there is a temporary solution by mention nodes in Storage plugin module as options key.

Like @Ryan mentioned in comment.

```
NgxsStoragePluginModule.forRoot({ key: ['auth'] })
```

But in above solution you will need to mention all the nodes you want to serialize.

In dev channel it is fixed, you can update package to `@ngxs/store@dev` and that would be fixed.
Updating the package to dev solved my problem.

Here you can see change log.
[Change log for NGXS](https://github.com/ngxs/store/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)